# Issue in accessing InfoPath form

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, forms-authentication

I am working with SharePoint 2013 Enterprise edition and InfoPath 2013.

The issue is that the created InfoPath forms which are published are not accessible by the users. It is an ongoing issue.

A possible cause of this issue may be the varying versions of InfoPath used across business users.

Do we need to consider the setup versions when using InfoPath for form creation? Or are there other issues we may need to take into consideration?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the problem is related to the infopath version. it seems the user does not has permission on the form library.

Make sure the user has permission on the form library.

Is there some error message?

Can you open the form in browser?

Besides, here is an article about InfoPath Error: Form Server Templates are not accessible for your reference:

http://www.keremozen.com/2014/06/02/infopath-error-form-server-templates-are-not-accessible/

Comment: Thanks Lisa. I'll check it out. All users have the same access and permission. It is a case that some can access and others are not able. Thanks for then link. I will see if there is anything in it that may help.